# Spanning columns in HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying do to a very simple operation of merging two columns in a table.  This seems easy with the colspan, but if I merge different columns without leaving at least one row without any merged columns, the sizing gets completely messed up.  Please see the following example at http://www.allthingsdope.com/table.html or take a look at and try the following code:

Good:

```
<table width="700px">
<tr>
    <th width="100px">1: 100px</th>
    <td width="300px">2: 300px</td>
    <td width="200px">3: 200px</td>
    <td width="100px">4: 100px</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width="100px">1: 100px</th>
    <td colspan=2 width="500px" >2 & 3: 500px</td>
    <td width="100px">4: 100px</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th width="100px">1: 100px</th>
    <td width="300px">2: 300px</td>
    <td colspan=2 width="300px">3 & 4: 300px</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Bad:

```
<table width="700px">
<tr>
    <th width="100px">1: 100px</th>
    <td colspan=2 width="500px" >2 & 3: 500px</td>
    <td width="100px">4: 100px</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width="100px">1: 100px</th>
    <td width="300px">2: 300px</td>
    <td colspan=2 width="300px">3 & 4: 300px</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This seems so simple but I cannot figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the width attribute on the individual cells.  This has been deprecated since at least html 4.01 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6, if you care that the w3c doesn't approve of your coding).  In any case, you run into all sorts of troubles if you try to mix this with colspans.

Instead, add [<col>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.2) elements to the table, like so:

```
    <table width="700px">
        <col width="100px"/>
        <col width="300px"/>
        <col width="200px"/>
        <col width="100px"/>
        <tr>
            <th>1: 100px</th>
            <td colspan="2">2 &amp; 3: 500px</td>
            <td>4: 100px</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1: 100px</th>
            <td>2: 300px</td>
            <td colspan="2">3 &amp; 4: 300px</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The <col> element exists precisely to serve as a placeholder on which to hang attributes that apply to an entire column.

Comment: I was actually controlling all the widths with CSS, but I like this method as well.  Thanks for the info, I always try to be as up to date with standards as I can be.

Comment: Understood.  The <col> widths can be set in CSS as well, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the width parameter in the merged column with "auto"-- it will get "whatever's left" which works out perfectly.  So:

```
<table width="700px" border="1px">
<tr>
    <th width="100px">1: 100px</th>
    <td colspan=2 width="auto"  >2 & 3: 500px</td>
    <td width="100px">4: 100px</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width="100px">1: 100px</th>
    <td width="300px">2: 300px</td>
    <td colspan=2 width="auto">3 & 4: 300px</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah, you are the man!  While I don't really understand why that works, it does.  Thanks so much for taking the time to answer, I've been racking my brain!